# Возможно ли отложить сборку мусора на детерминированный момент во времени?

Tags: сборщик-мусора

В качестве среды возьмем CLR. Язык - C# 5.
Допустим, есть некая среда реального времени. 
Необходимо отложить сборку мусора, скажем, на некий момент времени t ( и дальше сборку мусора должна происходить в опрделенные нами моменты времени).
Возможно ли сделать такое?

Возможно ли ограничить время работы GC? Скажем, установить некую опцию, и получить гарантию что GC неб удет работать больше, к примеру, чем N минут?

Comment: Каких-то очень гибких настроек для сборки мусора нет. Разработчики справедливо посчитали, что сборщик мусора лучше, чем программист знает, когда ему заниматься своими грязными делишками.  Впрочем, [кое-какие настройки][1] все же есть

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384202.aspx